# Does Aurelia support iframe tag: sandbox attribute?

Tags: aurelia

I am new to aurelia. This sample code under the html tab works fine in JSbin:
http://jsbin.com/yiqodilaho/edit?html,js,output
But generates an error in seeCode.run (the online editor that we are developing)
https://seecode.run/#-KAbCyh8F6SpHiTVpOfq .I found that its not working as iframe has set of restrictions and so doesnt allow scripts, API's or form submissions. So, I have used "Sandbox" attribute . sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts" and it working fine. Now, we have migrated the front end of the project to Aurelia and same problem has occured again. This time adding sandbox attribute couldnt make any difference. Can Somehow help me with this issue..? Does Sanbox attribute work in Aurelia?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if aurelia's binding system supports `<iframe sandbox.bind="tokens">`? It does not support this.  `HTMLIFrameElement.sandbox` is a `DOMSettableTokenList` which needs to be assigned like this: `f.sandbox.value = '...'` and aurelia is assigning it like this `f.sandbox = '...'`.

https://gist.run/?id=7dca16fd08dff85cf71f2fef1c439baf

You should be able to use it like this still:  `<iframe sandbox="allow-pointer-lock" ...`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771918(v=vs.85).aspx